# htaccess kills permissions

Tags: .htaccess, permissions

I'm trying to work with .htaccess, but it appears that whenever I put it in a folder, permissions to that folder (and everything inside it) are removed. I'm just trying something super basic:

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com [R]
```

Why are all permissions lost upon introduction of the .htaccess file? It has the same user and group, and permissions (which I tried changing to 777 - doesn't help) as everything else in the folder and even the folder itself...

Answer (score 0):

Chucked Options +FollowSymLinks in the appropriate httpd.conf and it worked.. Sigh